# How to do a rolling average over a row of dates and values?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

How would I do a rolling average over a row of dates and values?

The data basically looks like the following:

```
9/15/2010   199.8
9/14/2010   202
9/13/2010   200.8
9/12/2010   202.8
9/11/2010   201.4
9/10/2010   201.6
9/9/2010    201.8
9/8/2010    202.2
9/7/2010    202.2
9/6/2010    202.6
9/5/2010    205.8
9/4/2010    204.2
9/3/2010    205
9/2/2010    206.6
9/1/2010    208
8/31/2010   209.8
8/30/2010   210.2
8/29/2010   209.6
8/28/2010   209.6
8/27/2010   209.4
8/26/2010   209.8
8/25/2010   209.2
8/24/2010   210.8
```

Comment: are you looking for an average beside every row, or an average somewhere else that automatically adjusts as you add/remove/change data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your first piece of data is in B1, you can copy and paste the following formula down the length of your data column.  Put this in C2:

```
=AVERAGE($B$1:B2)
```

The dollar signs "anchor" the first cell, making it an absolute reference that doesn't move as you copy/paste the formula, while the second cell is a relative reference that will continue to update the average with each entry.

Comment: Hrm, I was honestly hoping for something simpler than a copy paste of the formula down the line. (not that this isn't what I asked for, it is)

Comment: @alt You don't get much simpler than *one* formula you just copy down the entire column, this is the way I'd do it. +1 @Michael.

Comment: You shouldn't be copying and pasting that. Enter the first one, select the whole column, then Edit&rarr;Fill&rarr;Down.

Comment: Using the fill function is what I called a "copy paste". Each cell is evaluated individually and could potentially be different. (though it wouldn't be)...

Answer (score 2):

By "Rolling Average", I believe you are talking about the average of the last n days (say 5 days).

(Base on the data you provided, assuming they are column A & B)

**Enter `=AVERAGE(OFFSET(B1,0,0,5))` into `C1`, then copy and paste it downwards (if necessary).**

`C1` should output `201.36` which is the average of the recent 5 days; `C2` is `201.72`, and so on.

---

Explaination:

`OFFSET()` outputs a range starting from `B1` with height of `5` (downwards, including `B1` itself).
**(Replace `5` with the number of days you want.)**

Then, `AVERAGE()` is used to compute the average of the range.

Answer (score 1):

```
=AVERAGE($B$1:INDEX($B$1:$B$100,COUNTA($B$1:$B$100)))
```

This will update as you add data.  But note that it only looks at the first 100 rows, so adjust if there's going to be more.  Also, if you insert lines at the top, the references will shift down.

Answer (score 0):

Having reviewing [my own answer](https://superuser.com/a/189242/43356) years later, I would like to suggest a simpler formula.

1. Input into C1 `=average(B1:B5)` (assume 5-day rolling average)
2. Copy and paste downwards in column C

Note: For the earliest record (8/24/2010), the rolling average (column C) will show the value of that day. For the second record (8/25/2010), it will show the average of first 2 days, and so on.